# React native react-native-google-signin not working

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, google-signin

I have a React Native Expo project in which I use the react-native-google-signin package. When I run it in development mode on my physical phone, it works, and I can log in. After building the app with the EAS builder and installing the release version on my phone, it still works for me. However, when I sent it to my friend, he couldn't log in. My friend doesn't encounter any errors, even though the login is within a try block and doesn't throw any exceptions. What could be the issue?

I've tried generating a new debug.keystore file, recreated the project several times, but nothing worked. The Google Console is configured correctly, and I've also set up Firebase.

EDIT: The Google Play Console is not set up, if that matters.

Comment: Can you show us the code of the try/catch where you are calling `.signIn()` ?  Without showing us code, it is hard to guess as to what the issue could be.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.